# Replace string contain "&" in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this string :
`"Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer"`

I try to replace this string by "" but it doesn't work.

```
var res = choix.replace("Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer","");
```

I think the pb is "&", but I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Try RegEx `console.log(choix.replace(/Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer/i,""));`

Comment: Your code works fine for me. @GuilhermeNascimento neither "&" nor ";" are regex metacharacters ...

Comment: `"Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer".replace('&','')` works fine

Comment: Wait - do you have that string in your HTML source, and are you then fetching it from the DOM with `.innerHTML` or something?

Comment: @Pointy Thanks +1, I agree your second comment (about `.innerHTML`)

Comment: its work perfectly, may be you are doing something else wrong in your code

Comment: Does `.replace("Parquets \u00E0 coller ou clouer"/i, "")` work?

Comment: .replace("Parquets \u00E0 coller ou clouer"/i, "") doesn't work,
choix is : var choix = jQuery('#materiaux .choix').html();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
choix = "Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer";

jQuery('#materiaux .choix').html(choix);

jQuery('#materiaux .choix').html(choix.replace("Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer", ""));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3tX9c/

Comment: choix is var choix is : var choix = jQuery('#materiaux .choix').html();

Comment: @user1377807 What are `#materiaux` and `.choix`? Can you add the HTML to your question?

Comment: `<div id="materiaux">
       <div class="choix"></div>
    </div>`

"Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer" are added into `.choix` with 
    `jQuery('#materiaux .choix').html("Parquets &agrave; coller ou clouer");`

Comment: @user1377807 Ok. I understand now. I think my new answer should work.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use regexp in first param of replace.

```
 var res = choix.replace(/Parquets \&agrave\; coller ou clouer/i,"");
```